# PHPMailer not sending from smtp host

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm using `PHPMailer` and I set it up to use `SMTP` for sending emails. The problem is,  it's not connecting to the SMTP server but instead its trying to send mail from the hosting server. Heres the code i created:

```
                $mail = new PHPMailer ( true );
                $mail->IsSMTP ();
                $mail->Host = $res ['outgoingmailserverhost'];
                if(in_array($res['outgoingmailserverencryptedconnectiontype'],array('ssl','tls'))){
                    $mail->SMTPSecure = $res ['outgoingmailserverencryptedconnectiontype'];
                }
                $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                $mail->Port = ( int ) $res ['outgoingmailserverport'];
                $mail->Username = $imapUser;
                $mail->Password = $imapPass;
                $mail->SetFrom($fromaddress,$fromname);
                $mail->AddReplyTo($fromaddress,$fromname);
                foreach($allrecipients as $type=>$recip){
                    foreach($recip as $recs){
                        if($type==='cc'){
                            $mail->AddCC($recs);
                        } elseif($type==='bcc'){
                            $mail->AddBCC($recs);
                        } elseif($type==='to'){
                            $mail->AddAddress($recs);
                        }
                    }
                }
                $mail->Subject = $subject;
                $mail->AltBody = $textbody;
                $mail->MsgHTML($htmlbody);
                if($attachment1!==null){
                    $attachment1= BASE_PATH . '/data/uploads/' . $attachment1;
                    $mail->AddAttachment($attachment1);
                }
                if($attachment2!==null){
                    $attachment2= BASE_PATH . '/data/uploads/' . $attachment2;
                    $mail->AddAttachment($attachment2);
                }
                if($attachment3!==null){
                    $attachment3= BASE_PATH . '/data/uploads/' . $attachment3;
                    $mail->AddAttachment($attachment3);
                }
                $mail->Send();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by commenting out `$mail->IsSMTP()`